# OWLAPI and Declaration Axiom requirements

Tags: java, scala, owl, owl-api

Reference code as a whole: https://github.com/jottinger/ontology

I'm creating an ontology and populating it (correctly, I think). The structure is there, but I'm not validating it yet.

However, I still keep expecting declarations to show up and I don't know why they're missing. I *think* it's got something to do with the prefix manager (because every element is fully qualified by the namespace) but I don't know how to instantiate a new prefix manager such that i can register namespaces.

Here's the code to add a subclass relationship:

```
val clazz = getOntClass(node.name)

val parent = getOntClass(data(node.p).name)
val hasClazz = getOntObjectProperty("has" + node.name)
val hasClazzSomeClazz = df.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(hasClazz, clazz)

val hasParent = getOntObjectProperty("has" + data(node.p).name)
val hasParentSomeParent = df.getOWLObjectSomeValuesFrom(hasParent, parent)
m.applyChanges(List(
  new AddAxiom(o, df.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(clazz)),
  new AddAxiom(o, df.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(clazz)),
  new AddAxiom(o, df.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(parent)),
  new AddAxiom(o, df.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(clazz, parent)),
  new AddAxiom(o, df.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(hasClazz)),
  new AddAxiom(o, df.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(parent, hasClazzSomeClazz)),
  new AddAxiom(o, df.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(parent)),
  new AddAxiom(o, df.getOWLDeclarationAxiom(hasParent)),
  new AddAxiom(o, df.getOWLSubObjectPropertyOfAxiom(hasClazz, hasParent))
))
```

I'm *assuming* that this is a valid structure. (Part of this project is to learn how ontologies work.) But I don't know how to get the declarations to appear, and this ontology is used as input for another process that wants that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to declare things more than once; those declarations are just identical. Besides that it seems that you code is correct (I'm speaking in terms of OWL API here; I don't know Scala enough to judge the correctness of Scala code)

Comment: Hah, I'd not noticed how many duplicates I had - but I *think* the problem is that the classes aren't showing up because I'm using the fully qualified IRI every time I refer to the types. I don't know how NOT to do that! With that said, thank you.

Comment: Using the full IRI is fine - it's actually better than using a prefix manager, in the sense that I see many people meeting with errors because they believe they are using certain prefix manager settings, while they are using others. Is this code modifying an existing ontology? To show the declarations just added in a file, you need to save the ontology through the manager.

Comment: I was trying to duplicate a file I'd created and saved through Protegé - using the full IRI is working well. With that said, though, I don't know how I'd use the Prefix Manager if I wanted to - I couldn't find an instantiation or an example of using one anywhere.